# iphone ViewDidAppear in SubViews?

Tags: iphone, subview, viewdidappear

I have a View "A", which loads a subview "B" which loads a subview "C"

Why does the ViewDidAppear event fire for "A" but not for "B" or "C"

ViewDidLoad does fire for A,B,C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The events like view[will,did][Appear,Disappear] do not get fired since they are handled by the viewController superclass, not the nib loader (which calls viewDidLoad when each of your other views are loaded from a nib).  You have to forward on these events by calling viewDidAppear yourself in any subviews (and really you meant subviews that are each managed by a view controller, right?) from the master viewDidAppear method, same thing for any of the other view controller methods you want fired in the subviews.